# How to replace $(data) in a string?

Tags: powershell, replace

I have a configuration file named `configuration.xml` and it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Configuration.xsd">

  <Icons>
    <Icon name="about" file="$(data)\more\data\about.png" />
    <Icon name="help" file="$(data)\more\data\help.png" />
  </Icons>

</Configuration>
```

For deploying these configuration file to different environments, I want to use a powershell script (currently PowerShell 5.1), which should replace the `$(data)` with the real path - `environment\path\to\data`.

A short version of my script looks like:

```bsh
$file = Get-Item '.\configuration.xml'
    
$content = ($file | Get-Content)

# file="$(data)\more\data" => file="environment\path\to\data\more\data"
$content = $content -replace '$(data)', 'environment\path\to\data'

$content | Set-Content $file.FullName
```

I tried to escape the `$` using single quotes and also tried to escape it with double quotes by using a backtick
`` "`$(data)" ``  but this does not work.

Also trying to solve it with using unicode `"$([char]0x0024)(data)"` was not successful.

Can somebody point me to a solution?

---

*Side note

I would like to change `$(data)`, but it is part of a 3rd party library, which I can't change. The 3rd party library uses `$(data)` to replace the path, and this path is configured in another file. In most cases it is use full, but in this particular use case I have to configure it for some instances/sub configurations with the full path.*

Comment: `$content -replace '$(data)', 'environment\path\to\data'` -> `$content -replace [regex]::escape('$(data)'), 'environment\path\to\data'`. The `()` characters have special significance in regex that need to be escaped as well. The regex escape character is \, which must be used here rather than the PowerShell escape character.

Comment: you may find it useful to study [ExpandString](https://nerdymishka.com/articles/expand-string-in-powershell/).  This is a built in tool that can plug in values for $variables in some defined scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `-replace` operator, regex is used to match a string. The regex matched string is replaced by a literal string with some exceptions. The general syntax is below:

```
$strings -replace $regex,$stringliteral
```

The regex must follow the regex escape rules rather than PowerShell escape rules. The regex escape character is `\`. Since `$()` are special characters in regex, your regex expression would need to be `\$\(data\)`. This can be done automatically for you through the regex `Escape()` method.

```
$file = Get-Item '.\configuration.xml'

$content = ($file | Get-Content)

$content = $content -replace [regex]::Escape('$(data)'), 'environment\path\to\data'

$content | Set-Content $file.FullName
```